# Citeproc YAML for a legal case citation

Tags: yaml, pandoc, cls

I am using Pandoc and want to cite a legal case. I want to enter the necessary data in YAML, similar to this:

```
  - title: One-click science marketing
  volume: '11'
  URL: http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmat3283
  DOI: 10.1038/nmat3283
  issue: '4'
  container-title: Nature Materials
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
    orcid: 0000-0003-1419-2405
  page: 261-263
  id: fenner2012a
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    date-parts:
      - 2012
      - 3
```

(Cited: [Blog entry by Martin Fenner](http://blog.martinfenner.org/2013/07/30/citeproc-yaml-for-bibliographies/))

After lengthy research I still don't know which fields I can use for a legal case. There are several CLS for legal cases, but I don't find any information what fields they expect. How I do find them out without reading through the CLS file, which I hardly understand?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am wondering myself right now as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the fields you can use for a legal case are shown in this Zotero entry exported to CSL JSON and then converted to CSL YAML. You will still have to find out which of the CSL files support these fields. https://forums.zotero.org/11/ may provide further assistance.

```
---
references:
- id: a
  type: legal-case
  author:
  - family: Author
    given: Al
  issued:
  - year: 1999
  title: Title
  container-title: Reporter
  authority: Court
  page: 123-456
  volume: 9
  number: Docket Number
  references: History
  abstract: Abstract
  language: en-US
...
```